# UITableView strange behaviour when using more than 1 Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, prototype, cells

So I have a UITableView which I plan to use 2 prototype cells inside of it.  Let's call them Cell A and Cell B.  Cell A has it's own layout and Cell B has it's own layout.

Here's the thing, in a typical UITableView implementation with only 1 prototype cell, after setting up all the cell and it's properties, cellForRowAtIndexPath takes care of populating all the rows based on the (x) number of items from numberOfRowsInSection.

Here is where I am having a problem.  I've implemented both my prototype cells in my UITableView and when I run it, I notice cellForRowAtIndexPath is only being called twice, even though I have a value in (x) number of items which is greater than 2.  Doesn't matter what I set it to, it only gets called twice.  I already have the necessary if statements to pick a cell prototype based on the cell index etc...so that's not the issue.  The issue is cellForRowAtIndexPath just gets called twice instead of looping thru all the items.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

This is my code for the DataSource methods:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 8

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    Scripts.log("Data Count = \(indexPath.row)")

    if indexPath.row == 0{

        var cell: ContactDetailImageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NAME_OF_CUSTOM_IMAGE_CELL) as ContactDetailImageCell

        cell.cardPhoto.image = aContact.profilePicture
        cell.fullName.text = aContact.getDisplayName()
        cell.workplace.text = aContact.workplace

        return cell

    }
    else{

        var cell: ContactDetailPhoneNumCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NAME_OF_CUSTOM_PHONE_CELL) as ContactDetailPhoneNumCell

        return cell

    }

    return UITableViewCell()

}
```

Comment: You need to show your code for the data source methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What height are your cells? cellForRowAtIndexPath will only get called if the table thinks it needs to display the cell. Hence the whole reuse mechanism. So if you have 8 cells and it thinks 2 fill the screen it will not ask for any more until you scroll up/down.

What are you returning for heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: OMG, I just tried this and scrolled and lo and behold, the other cells appear.  My "Cell A" has a height of 375 in the storyboard because I want to display an image there.  My "Cell B" has a height of "60" in the storyboard (but now that I tested it, I see it inherited a height of 375 from Cell A somehow at execution) and this is the cell that can be iterative based on # of records found.  So am I supposed to set the height of Cell B again manually in code or how do I fix this?

Comment: In iOS7 you have to tell it the height for each row by implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath. In iOS8 you can use the automatic cell sizing mechanism which does it for you. Can you accept this answer please as I answered the original problem.

Comment: Yes, I accept this answer.  I just got finished implementing the heightForRowAtIndexPath using the same if row == 0 else....logic I used in cellForRowAtIndexPath and now it is working fine like I wanted it to.  Thanks so much for your help!!!